# TypeError in py36compat

Tags: python-2.7

I get this strange error on Python2.7. It works fine with Python3:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/guettli/descript/projects/descript_jugendhaus/.tox/py27-django14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/guettli/descript/projects/descript_jugendhaus/.tox/py27-django14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/home/guettli/descript/projects/descript_jugendhaus/.tox/py27-django14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 195, in <module>
        distclass=BinaryDistribution,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 296, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 303, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 534, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 570, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-sy2MSY/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 118, in _add_defaults_ext
        if self.distribution.has_ext_modules():
      File "setup.py", line 109, in has_ext_modules
        return super().has_ext_modules() or 'SETUPPY_ALLOW_PURE' not in os.environ
    TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

What could be the root-cause?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

If I disable the `python-hunter` library it works.

I guess [python-hunter](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-hunter) is not compatible with Python2.7 any more.

That's fine for my use case. I this case I can remove the library (although it is a great tracing library).